# webpack bundle exceeds 2MB while reported module size is ~700k

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack with Typescript with this configuration:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/APIClient.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'reportserver.client.webpacked.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["dom", "es6"],
        "typeRoots": [ "./@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

I'm running *npx webpack --display-modules* and get:

```
mylib.webpacked.js  2.46 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = mylib.webpacked.js
 [0] ./node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js 1.97 KiB {0} [built]
 [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
 [2] ./src/utils/ArrayHelpers.ts 3.61 KiB {0} [built]
 [3] ./src/ApexChartProvider.ts 4.97 KiB {0} [built]
 [4] ./node_modules/promise-polyfill/src/finally.js 499 bytes {0} [built]
 [5] ./src/APIClient.ts 5.54 KiB {0} [built]
 [6] ./src/utils/HttpCllient.ts 1000 bytes {0} [built]
 [7] ./node_modules/promise-polyfill/src/index.js 5.82 KiB {0} [built]
 [8] ./node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js 6.32 KiB {0} [built]
 [9] ./node_modules/process/browser.js 5.29 KiB {0} [built]
[10] ./src/utils/HtmlHelpers.ts 780 bytes {0} [built]
[11] ./src/Report.ts 2.15 KiB {0} [built]
[12] ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js 157 bytes {0} [built]
[13] ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.prod.js 91.3 KiB {0} [built]
[14] ./node_modules/http-vue-loader/src/httpVueLoader.js 10.6 KiB {0} [built]
[15] ./node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.esm.js 442 KiB {0} [built]
[16] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {0} [built]
[17] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
[18] ./node_modules/vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.esm.js 73.2 KiB {0} [built]
[19] ./src/ReportModelCompiler.ts 8.88 KiB {0} [built]
```

Reported module size is less than 700KiB while bundle size is over 2MB. Where 1.3MB came form? Is it webpack overhead or some default polyfills?

Same build with browserify is about 1MB i've been counting that webpack will be better out of the box.

Thanks for any help
It Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it has to do with inlined source maps.

Check again with a production-ready value for webpack `devtool` option (or none):
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

you can also try the option `mode: 'production'`, but I don't recommend using that during development

Comment: Thanks very much that was it. Source map is 1.3MB as separate file when after changing devtool: 'inline-source-map' to devtool: 'source-map'